# Kusto Query limitation gets timeout error

Tags: kql, azure-monitor

I am running a Kusto Query in my Azure Diagnostics where I am querying logs of last 1 week and the query times out after 10 mins. Is there a way I can increase the timeout limits? if yes can someone please guide me the steps. I downloaded Kusto explorer but couldnt see any easy way of connecting my Azure cluster. Need help as how can i increase this timeout duration from inside Azure portal for query I am running?

Comment: It seems there is no way around the 10 minutes timeout. If you wish you can open a new question and share some detail regarding your scenario and your code, so we can see if there is a way to optimize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like 10 minutes are the max value for timeout.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/service-limits

**Query API**

| Category | Limit | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Maximum records returned in a single query | 500,000 |  |
| Maximum size of data returned | ~104 MB (~100 MiB) | The API returns up to 64 MB of compressed data, which translates to up to 100 MB of raw data. |
| **Maximum query running time** | **10 minutes** | **See Timeouts for details.** |
| Maximum request rate | 200 requests per 30 seconds per Azure AD user or client IP address | See Log queries and language. |

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/api/timeouts

**Timeouts**

> Query execution times can vary widely based on:
>
> - The complexity of the query
> - The amount of data being analyzed
> - The load on the system at the time of the query
> - The load on the workspace at the time of the query

> You may want to customize the timeout for the query.
> **The default timeout is 3 minutes, and the maximum timeout is 10 minutes.**

Comment: Thanks, raised another question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71758117/kusto-optimization-to-avoid-time-out