# Kusto optimization to avoid time out

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics

I am looking to optimize my kusto query which is getting timeout in 10 mins. I have to usually run it for a week period so there is less limit on the time

```
AzureDiagnostics 
| where TimeGenerated between (startofday(datetime("2022-03-26")) .. endofday(datetime("2022-04-04")))
| where Category == 'kube-audit'
| where log_s hasprefix '"code":2'
| where (strlen(log_s) >= 32000
and not(log_s has "aksService") 
and not(log_s has "system:serviceaccount:crossplane-system:crossplane")
and not(log_s has "system:serviceaccount:elastic-system:elastic-operator")
and not(log_s has "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:daemon-set-controller")
and not(log_s has "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:deployment-controller")
and not(log_s has "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:endpoint-controller")
and not(log_s has "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:node-controller")
and not(log_s has "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:replicaset-controller")
and not(log_s has "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:statefulset-controller"))
or strlen(log_s) < 32000
| extend op = parse_json(log_s) 
| where not(tostring(op.verb) in ("list", "get", "watch"))
| where not(tostring(op.user.username) hasprefix "system:")
| where not(tostring(op.user.username) in ("hcpService", "aksService", "aksProblemDetector", "readinessChecker", "nodeclient", "masterclient"))
| where not(tostring(op.requestURI) in ("/apis/authorization.k8s.io/v1/selfsubjectaccessreviews"))
| extend user = op.user.username
| extend decision = tostring(parse_json(tostring(op.annotations)).["authorization.k8s.io/decision"])
| extend requestURI = tostring(op.requestURI)
| extend name = tostring(parse_json(tostring(op.objectRef)).name)
| extend namespace = tostring(parse_json(tostring(op.objectRef)).namespace)
| extend verb = tostring(op.verb)
| project TimeGenerated, SubscriptionId, ResourceId, namespace, name, requestURI, verb, decision, ['user']
| order by TimeGenerated asc
```

Comment: Oh, *that* query :-) (1) could you share what `log_s` origin is? It is not part of the core fields https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/azurediagnostics (2) Do you have by any chance a column named `log_d`?

Comment: not very sure, how can I figure out the origin and how can I find if there is a column name log_d. This query was already built and was provided to me for optimizing purpose

Comment: `AzureDiagnostics | getschema | where ColumnName == 'log_d'` to look for a column

Comment: no we dont have log_d column

Comment: These are AKS logs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/monitor-aks-reference

Comment: Negation filtering is bad strategy, performance wise. Do you have any idea what kind of logs you are looking for?

Comment: As we know we don't have a choice to extend the time we only have an option now is optimizing the code and for that what we need to do is check each and every line and need to optimize that statement which take longer time to run